# GTK3 label scrollbar Python

Tags: python, label, scrollbar, gtk3

Here is notebook code with gtk3 python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window(title="Notebook")
window.set_default_size(600, 360)
window.connect("destroy", lambda q: Gtk.main_quit())

notebook = Gtk.Notebook()
window.add(notebook)

notebook.set_tab_pos(Gtk.PositionType.LEFT)

label0 = Gtk.Label() # need here scrollbar
label1 = Gtk.Label() # need here scrollbar

label0.set_text("First text inside")
label1.set_text("Second text inside")

notebook.append_page(label0)
notebook.append_page(label1)

notebook.set_tab_label_text(label0,"First tab title")
notebook.set_tab_label_text(label1,"Second tab title")

notebook.set_tab_reorderable(label1, False)

label0.set_alignment(0.0,0.0)
label1.set_alignment(0.0,0.0)

window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

[image]

How to add scrollbar on Labels? Not in main window or main container, but only in labels, where are "First Text inside, Second text inside" labels.

Answer (score 0):

`Gtk.Notebook` doesn't support that. If there are too many tab labels to fit in the space, then it will add arrows for paging through the tabs; I'm assuming that's not what you want.

Instead, use [`Gtk.StackSidebar`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStackSidebar.html) with `Gtk.Stack` (GTK 3.16 or later). If you have 3.10 or later, you can still use `Gtk.Stack` but you will have to build your own replacement for `Gtk.StackSidebar` which you can probably do quite easily with `Gtk.ListBox`.